# How to build 2 dotnet projects at the same time with the same dependency

Tags: c#, .net

Assume the following structure.

```
\A.csproj (Project Reference to \Infra.csproj)
\B.csproj (Project Reference to \Infra.csproj)
\otherapp\C.csproj (Project Reference to \..\Infra.csproj)
\Infra.csproj
```

I have multiple .net6 projects that have a single dependency. When I build them I want to build them all at the same time then run them all at once. The issue is that when one project builds the shared project, the second one will get stuck because the file is in use from the shared reference.

> The process cannot access the file '\Infra\obj\Debug\net6.0\Infra.dll' because it is being used by another process.

My script basically opens `dotnet watch` in a new cmd for all the apps at the same time.

How can I set this up so that multiple projects can be watched with the shared reference.

Comment: One solution should be duplicating .dll and referencing to this copy I guess.

Comment: What's your IDE and build stack? I think VS and msbuild are smart enough to determine dependency chains, for example.

Comment: im trying to do this via cli. So `dotnet watch` or `dotnet run`.